# How to create horizontal menu using jQuery 1.10.3 version

Tags: jquery, html

I need horizontal menu using jQuery 1.10.3 version. Actually jQuery demo has only vertical menu example but I need horizontal menu.

Comment: the principle is the same,  it's just the CSS that is different

Comment: Float left the list items....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">Ada</a></td>
<td><a href="#">Adamsville</a></td>
<td>
<a href="#">Addyston</a>
<ul>
<li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
<td><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can create horizontal menu using `<tr><td>` 
A menu can be created from any valid markup as long as the elements have a strict parent/child relationship and each menu item has an anchor.